# Convert in_Array call file from PHP to JSP

Tags: java, php, jsp

i'm new learn JSP, previously i can PHP.

i want convert this script PHP to script JSP.
i want create dynamic file, in JSP.

example i create index.jsp

```
header.jsp

    dynamicfile.php

footer.php
```

This dynamic file call like this  index.jsp?p=about

This about file from "pages/about.jsp"

this is script

```
<?php $pages_dir = 'pages';
if(!empty($_GET['p'])){
$pages = scandir($pages_dir, 0);
unset($pages[0], $pages[1]);

$p = $_GET['p'];
if(in_array($p.'.php', $pages)){
include($pages_dir.'/'.$p.'.php');
} else { ?>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=404.html" />
<?php }
} else {
include($pages_dir.'/beranda.php');
} ?>
```

This is my script index.jsp

```
<%
                String  pages_dir = "pages";
                String  pages;
                String  p = request.getParameter("p");

                 if(!empty(p))
                     pages = java.io.File dir = new java.io.File(pages_dir,0);

                String wew = p+".jsp";
                List nameList = Arrays.asList(wew);

            %>
```

This not clear, cause i confused.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/BVeTJsuk  << this not clear

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your question..

Comment: you can see coding in my questin, this is code php and i want this code to jsp. cause i learn jsp

Comment: Try to post your code in your question not as link in comment..

Comment: i updated my question

Comment: Your question is too broad to help. does this `pages` is a directory in your app.